# login twitter account in android app with twitter kit

Tags: twitter, account, checkin, twitterkit

I'm making an android app using Java as a language. The idea of ​​this app is to be able to log me in with my twitter account and be able to get the name, email and image of the account which should be shown in a kind of user profile in the app In order to log in, I'm using the package: twitterkit: 3.1.1 but I can't connect with my account, this is what I have so far:

```
public class loggin extends AppCompatActivity {

    //pruebas twitter:
    TwitterAuthClient mTwitterAuthClient;
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient;
    StatusesService statusesService;

    //variable twitter
    TwitterLoginButton login;
   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Twitter.initialize(this);
        login = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        login.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                login(session);
                Toast.makeText(loggin.this, "falto poco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(loggin.this, "casiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
 public void login(TwitterSession session){
        long userId = session.getUserId();
        String userName = session.getUserName();
        Intent intent =new Intent(loggin.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("username",userName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        login.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: You probably already know that Twitter Kit is no longer supported, but what do you mean by "can't connect with my account" - what is the error?

Comment: that when you click on the twitter login button, the failure method message is executed. What tool can you recommend me to log into twitter apart from back4app? since I want to handle the db with sqlite